# Making a unique list that is paired to the header (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Let's say I have a data set sorted like this

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | f | g |
| b | g | b | c |
|  | h |  | i |
|  | k |  |  |

The data in the table have identical values, differed only by the header.

I'd like to have a pair of list made from this table like the following

| Header | Data |
| --- | --- |
| A | a |
| A | b |
| B | e |
| B | g |
| B | h |
| B | k |

....

A data column accompanied by another column containing its header value. Blanks are to be skipped so it uses less space. If the table hadn't contained identical values, it would be easier to make a formula but the identical data makes it a little too complicated for me.

Comment: What about header `C` and `D`.

Comment: How to behave on duplicates? First appearance header?

Comment: Power Query seems logic here: unpivot / remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be achieved without blanks with formulas, so in case a VBA solution might work for you, you can do like this:

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim MyData As Variant

MyData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
LC = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

'let's say you want output starting in column F
Range("F1").Value = "Header"
Range("G1").Value = "Data"

k = 2 'starting row where to paste data

For j = 1 To LC Step 1 'iterate columns
    For i = 2 To UBound(MyData) Step 1 'iterate rows starting at row 2 (row 1 is headers)
        If MyData(i, j) <> "" Then
            'if not blank, paste data
            Range("F" & k).Value = MyData(1, j) 'get header always from row 1
            Range("G" & k).Value = MyData(i, j) 'get data
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j

Erase MyData

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer my question. I'm not quite sure wear to paste this, however, and I've tried creating a module but apparently that's not where it's meant to be. I've come up with a solution to make a pivot table with a VBA to keep updating it so I think I don't need anything else at the momement. Thanks once again.